# Rails Conditional Statements on Object Index Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, if-statement

In my rails app, I have an index of an object I'm calling Lessons.  If a user marks the lesson as being completed, it gets recorded in a join table called Completions and the completed_step boolean gets set to true.

In the show action for the lesson, I'm able to insert a conditional statement to modify the button for "Complete Lesson."

That button logic works fine like this:

```
<% if current_user.completed_steps.include? @lesson %>                
   <%= button_to "This Lesson is Completed", @lesson.next, class: "btn btn-success btn-lg", :method => :get  %>               
<% else %>
   <%= button_to "Mark this Lesson as Complete", complete_lesson_path, class: "btn btn-warning btn-lg" %>
<% end %>
```

My question is how do I incorporate this type of logic check on the index view?

I'd like the links to each Lesson to appear in a Bootstrap Panel and I want to change the color of the panel depending upon whether or not the user completed_step for each Lesson.

I tried wrapping the panel in the same statement and it doesn't work, it stays red even though the user has completed these lessons.

Here's what I attempted:

```
<% @lessons.each do |lesson| %>

          <% if current_user.completed_steps.include? @lesson %>  
            <div class="panel panel-success">
          <% else %>
            <div class="panel panel-danger">
          <% end %>
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">
                  <%= link_to(lesson) do %>
                        <strong><%= lesson.title %></strong>
                  <% end %>
                </h3>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                <td><%= lesson.summary %></td>
              </div>
            </div>
```

What am I doing wrong or why isn't this working?

Comment: I think you should change `<% if current_user.completed_steps.include? @lesson %>` to `<% if current_user.completed_steps.include? lesson %>`. This might work.

Comment: That did it, thanks!!  Can't believe it was that simple.  Yikes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change your script

```
 <% @lessons.each do |lesson| %>

          <% if current_user.completed_steps.include? lesson %>  
            <div class="panel panel-success">
          <% else %>
            <div class="panel panel-danger">
          <% end %>
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">
                  <%= link_to(lesson) do %>
                        <strong><%= lesson.title %></strong>
                  <% end %>
                </h3>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                <td><%= lesson.summary %></td>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass same object as you given in in you for loop .

```
<% @lessons.each do |lesson| %>

<% if current_user.completed_steps.include? lesson %>  
            <div class="panel panel-success">
          <% else %>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Pramod Gupta is right. Also, look into using Presenters for this type of logic that is used for decorating the views.